# Infinite socle series

Tags: abstract-algebra, socle

Is it possible for a finite dimensional $k$-algebra $A$ ($k$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$) to have an infinite socle series?

Namely, I have calculated the radical and socle for $T_n(k)=$ the lower triangular matrices.
I found (I will demonstrate the $3 \times 3$ case

$$rad T_n(k) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\
x & 0 & 0\\
y & z &0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and so

$$rad^2 T_n(k) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
y & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and $rad^3 T_n(k) = 0$. If we consider the simple modules or, equivalently, consider what is annihiliated by radical of $T_n(k)$ we come up with the diagonal matrices

$$soc T_n(k) = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & 0\\
0 & 0 & c \end{pmatrix}$$

which is clearly not nilpotent. I was under the impression the socle series was supposed to terminate but it seems this is a solid counter example unless I have made a mistake.

Comment: Any increasing or decreasing sequence of linear subspaces stabilizes in a finite dimensional space.

Comment: This is definitely stable. It just doesn't stabilize trivially.

Answer (score 1):

The socle series stabilizes in any Artinian ring, just like any ascending chain.

A finite dimensional $k$-algebra is (two-sided) Artinian, because every left or right ideal is a $k$-vector subpace.

The socle of a ring is a two-sided ideal, so what you found is *not* the socle.

Comment: So where did I go wrong?

Comment: @AaronZolotor What's the annihilator of the radical?

Comment: $ann rad T_n(k) = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0\\ b & 0 & 0\\ c & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @AaronZolotor And then, why are you talking about diagonal matrices?

Comment: I thought the socle was the collection of things annihiliated by the radical, not the annihilator of the radical? Since the socle is the sum of all simple modules my definition seems to hold.